# HTML tags in strings break javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("p").click(function(){
$(".Part1 p").html("some new text that will replace what <br /> was in the paragraph.   <p> and a paragraph </p>");
});
```

Edit: added ); to the end for clarity.

When I try to put html tags in my strings it either doesn't show up at all as is the case of `<br />` or it breaks the script and I get an error as is the case of  `</p>`

How can I added html tags to strings so that I can have my text formatted the way I want but still make dynamic changes?

Comment: That should work perfectly. Can you post a link to a live demo?

Comment: That's a good idea I should have thought of that first. Let me see if I can get it up somewhere. Speaking of which does anyone know a convenient place to host demo files for a short time?

Comment: Strangely, it works on jsfiddle and in the actual file =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/D6XCv/

But maybe you forgot to close the ")" for the click() event :

```
$("p").click(function() {
    $(".Part1 p").html("some new text that will replace what <br /> was in the paragraph.   <p> and a paragraph </p>");
}); // <== this ")" !
```

Comment: Thanks for the site actually I just grabbed that line from a larger piece of code that I had written, in that one the i closed it correctly sorry for the confusion

Comment: When I tested it on that site it worked as well. Really strange that it works in one place and not another.

Comment: That means the problem is from somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

The `<br />` shouldn't be a problem, but a `<p>` element cannot be a child of another `<p>` element, so you are trying to construct an invalid DOM (and so errors are to be expected).

Comment: I see what you are saying even when I do it with <span> tags it does the same thing (it actually deletes the text that is found within the tags). I'm using TextWrangler and when in the string it gets to '</' I lose all my code coloring for the rest of the <script>

Answer (score 0):

When I tested this in a browser, I needed to append a trailing `);`

```
$("p").click(function(){
$(this).html("some new text that will replace what <br /> was in the paragraph.
    <p> and a paragraph </p>");
});
```

Comment: I just grabbed that line from a larger piece of code that I had written, in that one the I closed it correctly sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using TextWrangler and when in the string it gets to '<script>

The sequence `</` will end the parsing of a script element under SGML (and thus HTML 4) rules (although it isn't respected so much by many browsers).

Either:

1. Use an external script file and `src` it or
2. Escape the slash character: `<\/`

Comment: When I used <\/ my code highlighting came back on but then when I tried to run it in the browser I got this error. 

error on line 17 at column 144: StartTag: invalid element name